# OneDrive has issues syncing up

Tags: sharepoint-online, onedrive-for-business

One out of 170 users is having issues syncing files occasionally to SharePoint Online Document Library.
She has no problem downloading them, but many files she creates would not sync up and will always show the status of sync in progress.
Tried following:
* Replacing the desktop computer
* Installing all updates

Comment: Is this user able to create files directly in the library or upload to the library? What permission does this user have in this library?  Try “Unlink this PC” or switch to another network.

Comment: Ya, she's got Edit access to the library. One of the techs worked on this issue, which resulted in proper sync for couple of days, and then issue re-appeared.